# To display sum of two fields entered on visualforce page and display the same on visualforce page

Tags: salesforce

I want to calculate the sum of two fields which user has entered on visualforce page and calculate total in a total field and update the total field on visualforce page once fields are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Logic for performing the calculation depends on whether you want to do it at controller level or at client side.

For controller:
On a click of command button, call action method in salesforce.

```
<apex:page controller="MathematicalOperations">
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue1}" id="theTextInput1"/>
        <apex:inputText value="{!inputValue2}" id="theTextInput2"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!calculateSum}" id="sum"/>
       <apex:commandbutton action="{!calcuateSum}" value="Calculate Sum" rerender="frm"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page
```

>

```
public class MathematicalOperations()
{
    public decimal inputValue1{get;set;}
    public decimal inputValue2 {get;set;}
    public decimal sum {get;set;}
    public void calculateSum()
    {
        sum = inputValue1 + inputValue2;
   }
}
```

If my solution has solved your issue please mark it as solved.

Thanks,
Mayank